# How can i print "There are XXX observations satisfying that condition." with the pipeline value?

Tags: r

I am trying to get an output "There are XXX observations satisfying that
condition." after a pipeline with XXX being the value i get after my pipeline.

Comment: Please don't vandalise your post. If you have a solution, accept it by clicking the tick to the left of the answer that helped you the most.

Comment: My guess as to the downvotes is that your question is not very clear. It would be really helpful if you included a snippet of code that contained the pipeline, so it's clearer what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
iris %>% summarise(n = n()) %>% pull(n) -> XXX
glue::glue('There are {XXX} values after satisfying the condition')

There are 150 values after satisfying the condition
```

Answer (score 0):

```
paste0("There are ", iris %>% summarise(n = n()) %>% pull(n), " values after satisfying the condition")
```

[1] "There are 150 values after satisfying the condition"

Comment: If you're going to do it with `dplyr`, then at least keep the pipe external: `iris %>% summarise(n = n()) %>% pull(n) %>% paste0("There are ", ., " values after satisfying the condition")`. I don't think that's the best way to do it (and think `glue` might be preferred by some), but I think it's more consistent.